# Letter Count: return the first word with the greatest number of repeated letters

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Can anyone help me out with the bug? This is a letter count challenge that you need to return the first word with greatest number of repeated letters, e.g.: Input = "Hello apple pie" Output = Hello

I tried many different ways to debug my code and notice that the string didn't pass into the while loop, but I have no ideas why. Can anyone explain?

```js
function LetterCount(str) { 
  str = str.split(" ");
  var index = 0;
  while(index >= str.length){
   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      var str1 = str[i].split("").sort();
      for(var k = 0; k < str1.length; k++){
        
       if(index === 0 && str1[k] === str[k+1]){
          return str[i];
       }
       else if(index > 0 && str1[k] === str[k+1]){
          return str[i];
       }
      }
    }
    index++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Index is 0 so it will never be bigger than the str.length, the while loop will not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some regex magic to pull it off as well. ;)

```
function LetterCount(str) {
    var parts = str.replace(/(\s+)|([A-Z]*?)([A-Z])(\3+)([A-Z]*)|([A-Z]+)/gi, "$1$2$3$4$5$6,$3$4,").split(',');
    var firstIndexOfMaxLetters, maxCount = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2)
        if (parts[i].length > maxCount)
            { maxCount = parts[i].length; firstIndexOfMaxLetters = i; }
    return firstIndexOfMaxLetters ? parts[firstIndexOfMaxLetters-1] : "";
}
LetterCount("Hi apPple pie")
```

Output: `"apPple"`

The regex turns the string into this:

```
["Hi", "", " ", "", "apPple", "pPp", " ", "", "pie", ""]
```

... where every second item in the array is the repeating letters (if any, or blank otherwise), and the word is before it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look as Ewald said your **index** is 0 so while loop won't be execute. I think will be easier if you store letters on a dictionary.

```
var niceDict = {};
//save letter and set initial value to zero
var letter = 'e';
niceDict[letter] = 0; // or niceDict['e'] = 0;
//incremente value
niceDict[letter]++;
```